# analytic geometry , perpendicular planes and a line

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Find a equation to the plane that contain the line $X = (1,0,2) + t(4,1,0)$ and is perpendicular to the plane $A : 3x + y + z = 0$

Comment: You need two directional vectors for your plane. The plane contains a given line, so..... The plane is perpendicular to another plane. What's the normal of that plane? Can you put the pieces together?

Comment: I used n1 * n1 = 0 and r * n1 = 0 but only this will not solve . ( n1 is the normal vector of the unknown plane , n2 is the normal vector of the plane A , r is the known line )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired plane is

$$(1,0,2) + s(3,1,1) + t(4,1,0)$$

It contains the line X (set s=0) and it contains the line

(1,0,2) + s(3,1,1) (set t=0) which is orthogonal to the plane A.

You only have to transform the parameter form into the normal form.

Comment: @user2803490 This was the approach I was hinting at (+1)

Answer (score 0):

$\nabla A=(3,1,1)$ so our plane is parellel to both the vectors $(4,1,0)$ and $(3,1,1)$. So it is perpendicular to vector $V=(4,1,0)\times (3,1,1)$. then $V=(1,-4,1)$. Our plane also contain the point (1,0,2) so equation of the plane is $$(1,-4,1).(x-1,y,z-2)=0$$ then we get $x-4y+z=3$.